# Working on a multi-language (C++/JavaScript) project in eclipse

Tags: javascript, c++, eclipse, ide

I am working on a codebase that uses a mixture of C++ and JavaScript, and I would like to use Eclipse as my IDE.

I have installed both CDT and JSDT, but I'm wondering how to actually use them together.

Is it necessary to create a separate project for the C++ code and a separate project for the Javascript code? In the code hierarchy, C++ and Javascript files are mixed together, it's not like there is one folder for each.

Or is it possible to seamlessly use the two languages in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go here is to create two separate projects. When you create the c++ project, you can simply add the javascript project as a referred project. This way you can exchange resources.

Comment: What do you mean by "exchange resources"?